# How to convert Long string of numbers from a CSV file to an array?

Tags: php, arrays, excel, csv

I have a CSV file with around 800 number of 5 digits each. I want to create an array with each element being one number of five digits. I am not very proficient in Excel, but I copied the list of numbers and created a string of the number. However, because I copied if from an Excel file, when I pasted it into my PHP code, it pasted one number per line, creating a string that is ~800 lines long. That is fine, but now that I want to create the array using the `$cbsa_keys_as_array = str_split($cbsa_keys, 5);` function, php counts each line break as a character, so that my second element is only four digits long, throwing everything off.

Comment: Why don't you use `explode` to split it at newlines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split it on the newlines with `explode`:

```
$cbsa_keys_as_array = explode("\n", $cbsa_keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the linebreaks and then split it.

```
$cbsa_keys = preg_replace("/\r|\n/", "", $cbsa_keys);
$cbsa_keys_as_array = str_split($cbsa_keys, 5);
```